# How can I delete everything in a Google Sheets column after a specified character

Tags: google-sheets

How can I delete everything in a Google Sheets column after a specified character.
For example how could I keep only the text before the / (GOOGL/US02079K3059).
I'm looking for something which could do this for an entire column at once.

I tried using the find and replace feature, but I couldn't figure out how to delete everything after a certain character.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the data in A2:A, you can use

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A,"/"),,1))
```